# Count merged observations and calculate fraction

Tags: count, stata

I merged two data sets using Stata and now I need to find the fraction and number of projects matched. To do this, I am assuming that I will need to calculate two counts.

How do I get both of the counts to display at the same time, and then divide one by the other?

Below is an example of my `_merge` variable:

```
4022. | master only (1) |
4023. |     matched (3) |
4024. |  using only (2) |
4025. |  using only (2) |
4026. |  using only (2) |
4027. |     matched (3) |
4028. |     matched (3) |
4029. |     matched (3) |
4030. |     matched (3) |
```

I would first like to count and store all of the variables under `_merge`, and then count those that don't say "master only". Then divide the two by each other.

For example:

```
count1    count2    fraction
6019      4020      .66 (4020/6019)
```

With `count1` being everything under `_merge`, while `count2` being everything that was matched (excludes master only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following toy example:

```
clear

webuse autosize
merge 1:1 make using http://www.stata-press.com/data/r14/autoexpense
```

First it is a good idea to confirm the value which corresponds to "master only":

```
list _merge

     +-----------------+
     |          _merge |
     |-----------------|
  1. |     matched (3) |
  2. |     matched (3) |
  3. |     matched (3) |
  4. | master only (1) |
  5. |     matched (3) |
     |-----------------|
  6. |     matched (3) |
     +-----------------+

list _merge, nolabel

     +--------+
     | _merge |
     |--------|
  1. |      3 |
  2. |      3 |
  3. |      3 |
  4. |      1 |
  5. |      3 |
     |--------|
  6. |      3 |
     +--------+
```

Then generate the three variables by first counting the relevant observations and dividing:

```
count if _merge
generate count1 = r(N)

count if _merge != 1
generate count2 = r(N)

generate fraction = count2 / count1

display count1
6

display count2
5

display fraction
1.2
```